# React does not recognize defined function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

The problem occurs when I do try to fire onClick function linked with the **ButtonWithDate** component ( it is being inherited from the parent component ):

```
<Button
    variant="extendedFab"
    onClick={this.props.updateDateAndHour}
    color="primary">
    Display Date
</Button>
```

Once I use it, the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: _services_API__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.default.getResponse is not a function
```

Bind of updateDateAndHour func:

```
<ButtonWithDate updateDateAndHour={this.updateDateAndHour}></ButtonWithDate></center>
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import API from './services/api';
import ButtonWithDate from './components/ButtonWithDate';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state= {
      'day': '',
      'month': '',
      'year': ''
    };
    this.API = API;
  }

  updateDateAndHour = () => {
    console.log(this);
    var self = this;
    API.getResponse().then((res) => {
      var local_date = res.date.split('-');
      self.setState({
        day: local_date[0]
      })

      self.setState({
        day: local_date[1]
      })

      self.setState({
        day: local_date[2]
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <center>
          <ButtonWithDate updateDateAndHour={this.updateDateAndHour}></ButtonWithDate></center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

services/api.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
const URL = 'https://...';

export default class API{
    getResponse() {
        axios.get(URL)
        .then(result => {
            return result
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return null;
        });
    }
};
```

components/ButtonWithDate.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

export default class ButtonWithDate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="button-container">
        <Button
          variant="extendedFab"
          onClick={this.props.updateDateAndHour}
          color="primary">
          Display Date
        </Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ButtonWithDate.propTypes = {
  onClickButton: PropTypes.func
}
```

When I do use a console.log along with the function name, I can easily access the content of it:

```
  updateDateAndHour = () => {
    console.log(getResponse);
    getResponse()...
```

but once I invoke **getResponse()**, an exception takes a place.

Screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: Your codes are hard to follow; also missing some parts

Comment: post has been updated

Comment: add screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

first of all sounds like there is a problem with `this` binding;

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    ...
    this.updateDateAndHour = this.updateDateAndHour.bind(this);
  }

  updateDateAndHour(){
      ...
  })

  ...
  }
```

you can use [babel proposal class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) to automatically to those bindings for you instead of manually doing every time
checkout this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/) for further reading;

---

However the main problem is in your `./api/` it's simpler to export `getResponse()` like below

> services/api.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
const URL = 'https://...';

const getResponse = () => {
        axios.get(URL)
        .then(result => {
            return result
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return null;
        });
}

export default getResponse;
```

---

EDIT:
for the sake the debugging cut getResponse() body in your `/api/` and use it in `updateDateAndHour(){ ... })` to see if it's working or not ( to see if the problem is in importing or the function itself )

Comment: I have tried the solution, but it does produce following error: 

TypeError: Object(...)(...) is undefined
App/_this.updateDateAndHour

Morever, should the invokement of getResponse function still remain like this: API.getResponse()? I do believe that I should siply use getResponse()

Comment: @ArturDrożdżyk consider importing like `import getResponse from './services/api';` then you can use like `getResponse()`

Comment: That is the way I have used it. When I try to use console.log(getResponse), I can't see any exceptions. Once I invoke the function like getResponse(), I do receive them

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue was connected with with usage of

```js
.then((res) => {
    var local_date = res.date.split('-');
    self.setState({
    day: local_date[0]
})
```

**getResponse()** function was not returning a new Promis object. That was the problem.

Quick-fix:
api.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';
const DATE_JSON_URL = 'https://...';


function getResponse() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(URL)
        .then(result => {
            resolve(result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            reject(error);
        })
    })
}

export default getResponse;
```